# Getting the current Experiment instance at runtime

Tags: anylogic

I'm running JUnit 4 with AnyLogic. In one of my tests, I need access to the `Experiment` running the test. Is there any clean way to access it at runtime? E.g., is there a static method along the lines of `Experiment.getRunningExperiment()`?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a static method that I know of (and, if there was, it might be complicated by multi-run experiments which permit parallel execution, although perhaps not since there's still a single Experiment, though there'd be thread-safety issues).

However, you can use `getEngine().getExperiment()` from *within* a model. You probably need to explain more about your usage context. If you're using AnyLogic Pro and exporting the model to run standalone, then you should have access to the experiment instance anyway (as in the help "Running the model from outside without UI").

Are you trying to run JUnit tests from *within* an Experiment? If so, what's your general design? Obviously JUnit doesn't sit as well in that scenario since it 'expects' to be instantiating and running the thing to be tested. For my automated tests (where I can't export it standalone because I don't use AnyLogic Pro), I judged that it was easier to avoid JUnit (it's just a framework after all) and implement the tests 'directly' (by having my model components write outputs and, at the end of the run in the Experiment, having the Experiment compare the outputs to pre-prepared expected ones and flag if the test was passed or failed). With AnyLogic Pro, you could still export standalone and use JUnit to run the 'already-a-test' Experiments (with the JUnit test checking the Experiment for a `testPassed` Boolean being set at the end or whatever).

The fact that you want to get *running* experiments suggests that you're potentially doing this whilst runs are potentially executing. If so, could you explain a bit about your requirements?

Comment: I'm running JUnit tests from within an experiment, yes. I'm not using it to test the model as a whole: I'm using it to test *model components.* (That's the point of JUnit and unit testing in general, after all.) My tests disconnect people, buildings, subsystems, and so on from the rest of the model and test them individually. For non-Agents, that's easy. For Agents, well, that took some time. I'd use `getEngine()` on them, but the issue is that I have to give them an `Engine` in the first place, which is why I need the call. Right now I have a working "solution," but it's certainly a hack.

Comment: OK; I assumed you were unit testing components. But you can set up top-level Agents which just compose the component(s) under test (with fake/mock Agents/objects if needed) and, since they're run in an Experiment, they have access to the Engine instance. Then have them output files as needed for your test (e.g., using Java logging) and/or use plain-old Java assertions.

Comment: But I agree that it would be cool if you could get JUnit working inside the Experiment, which is just a 'shell' to call it. You probably need to explain more about your design to think about what might be possible; e.g., how are you instantiating Agents if they're not directly contained in another Agent? I'm very interested in your architecture anyway, so feel free to msg me separately.